# How to prevent Spring from subclassing a class that implements a repository interface?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have these types:

```java
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {
    public Optional<Foo> getBySomeProperty(someProperty: String);
}

public class JpaRepositoryWrapper<T, ID> {

    private final JpaRepository<T, ID> repository;

    public JpaRepositoryWrapper(JpaRepository<T, ID> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}

@Component
@NoRepositoryBean // No effect
public class FooRepositoryWrapper
    extends JpaRepositoryWrapper<Foo, String> 
    implements FooRepository {

    private FooRepository repository;

    public FooRepositoryWrapper(FooRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // implement FooRepository methods by delegation to this.repository
    // ...
}
```

As expected, Spring will automatically provide a bean that implements `FooRepository`. It will also automatically provide a bean that is a subclass of `FooRepositoryWrapper`. The latter causes unintended side-effects which I have not shown here. How can I prevent Spring from subclassing `FooRepositoryWrapper`? The annotation `@NoRepositoryBean` has no effect here. Making the class final will yield a runtime error.

The only workaround I have come up with is adding another interface

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IFooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {
    public Optional<Foo> getBySomeProperty(someProperty: String);
}
```

and adjusting the existing types to:

```java
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends IFooRepository {
}

@Component
public class FooRepositoryWrapper
    extends JpaRepositoryWrapper<Foo, String>
    implements IFooRepository {

    // same as before
    // ...
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: It probably doesn't change anything, but please remove the `@Repository` annotations they are superfluous.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducer and create an issue? This looks like a bug to me https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACMNS/issues